# Call to a member function getActiveSheet() on a non-object, PHPExcel error

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am trying to get the value of a cell by PHPExcel

This works

```
$cell = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B2');
echo $cell->getCalculatedValue(); //Prints the cell value, Working
```

But when i put it to function it not works

```
function getval($id){
 $cell = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($id);
 return $cell->getCalculatedValue();
}
```

Says Call to a member function getActiveSheet() on a non-object

Comment: its a scope issue http://nz1.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: @Dagon I tried adding global to $objPHPExcel. 
global $objPHPExcel;
But stills not works.

Comment: Is `getval()` in another script file?

Answer (score 0):

the same thing came to me!

and i find answer,
objexcel is a class,you must new an object first!
so add

```php
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
```

in the function and use it next!